# SVG:TEXT attributes accessing in Javascript

Tags: text, svg

I have the HTML elements like the following:

```
<svg width="930" height="450">
  <g transform="translate(.5,.5)">
    <g class="cell" transform="translate(758.6842105263157,0)">
      <text x="85.65789473684211" y="225" dy=".35em" id="text-Summer" text-anchor="middle"  style="display: block;">Summer</text>
    </g>
   <g class="cell" transform="translate(758.6842105263157,0)">
      <text x="85.65789473684211" y="225" dy=".35em" id="text-Winter" text-anchor="middle" style="display: block;">Winter</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How can I get the "id" of the svg:text element which is having the text content "Summer" in **Javscript**.

I tried accessing using

```
$("svg g text[text='Summer']").attr('id').
```

But it is not getting.

Comment: This is not Javascript.

Comment: What Benio means is that $() is not in the JavaScript standard. I assume you're using jQuery, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
$("svg g text:contains(Summer)").attr('id')
```

It means that your selector is not correct.

Comment: The `svg g` actually isn't necessary. So you could just write `$("text:contains(Summer)").attr("id")`.

Comment: We don't actually know, if the topic starter really needs that `svg g`. So I decided to save it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but what for do you need this? Can't you just generate id and text at one time and then get the element with `$("svg g text#text-Summer")`?